# Calling methods with the correct Guice bindings

Tags: java, integration-testing, junit4, guice

Does [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) provide any means for "manually" calling methods with the correct Guice bound parameters? Like it does automatically for [provider methods](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) or constructors when using [constructor injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections)? Example:

```
@Inject
public void myMethod(Component component, @Productive Configuration configuration) {
    // ...
}
```

---

*Background:* I wrote a [JUnit](http://junit.org/) based integration test framework which uses Guice for dependency injection. Each test suite or case can declare the [modules](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Module.html) it would use. Here's an example of an integration test:

```
@RunWith(GuiceRunner.class)
@GuiceModules(SomeIntegrationTestModule.class)
public class SomeIntegrationTestSuite {

    @Inject
    Component component;

    @Test
    public void someIntegrationTest() {
        // do something with component
    }

}
```

This works very well and I can easily switch the module configuration just by adding / removing values to / from `@GuiceModules`. Most test cases however require different objects (`component` in the example above), so they all add up in the class declaration. What I'd like to have is something like this:

```
@RunWith(GuiceRunner.class)
@GuiceModules(SomeIntegrationTestModule.class)
public class SomeIntegrationTestSuite {

    @Test
    @Inject
    public void someIntegrationTest(Component component) {
        // do something with component
    }

}
```

I do know how I can extend JUnit in order to run test methods myself, but I don't know how I can call methods with the correct bindings using a [Guice Injector](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Injector.html) for resolving the formal parameters to Guice managed objects.

In short: How can I invoke methods like `someIntegrationTest(Component component)` with the correct Guice managed bindings (including support for [scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes), [binding annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations), ...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass an `Injector` object to your JUNIT setup method and then use that to get your injected `Component` object.

Something like this

```
injector.getInstance(Component);
```

would return your Guice injected object

Comment: Yes I know. But I don't want to analyse the parameters myself (remember e. g. binding annotations), because the functionality is already there:  Guice injects all dependencies into @Provides methods and constructors. Both can take arguments the same way as the test method `someIntegrationTest` does.